# PowerBi: Mulitple Slicer on single table

Tags: filtering, powerbi, slicers

I have the following table.

```
code    reference   name
291     6           Slovenian   
290     6           Serbo-Croatian  
289     6           Polish  
288     6           Czech(Ceske)    
287     6           Hrvatski    
189     6           Ukrainian   
72      10          Friend  
71      10          CD Rack 
7       10          CD-ROM Holder   
69      10          Shelf   
68      10          My computer 
57      6           Russian 
24      6           Italian 
23      6           French  
22      6           German
21      6           English
```

Now I want to have two slicer on my dashboard to have different filters for my table. At first I make a slicer for field: name and added a filter with the data field reference = 10. So all 5 Names are showed in the slicer. OK.
But... when I now added a second slicer for the same field but different reference = 6, PowerBi changed the first filter to  = 6 also. So I have two equal slicer instead of different ones.

How can I make different slicers for the same field with different filter criteria?

Example:

- First slicer: show me all name rows with reference = 10
- Second slicer: show me all name rows with reference = 6

Thanks in advance
Talcom

Comment: Why not select both on a single slicer? Just turn on multi-select under the slicer Format settings.

Comment: in the table are 570 different rows with 10 different reference values. its to much for one slicer

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's all about how you set up the data. I would create new columns to use as a filter. Technically you could use them to slice as well.

You could create a new column for both reference numbers:

```
is_10 = IF(table[reference]=10,1,0)
```

Repeat for 6.

Now you have 2 new columns to use as filters. Set filter to include only 1 for each where applicable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried it out but the main problem is still the same. if i want to make two slicers based on the field "name" the filters are still the same for both. I can't make one slicer with is_10 and the other one with is_6. At the end I want one slicer with (Slovenian, Serrbo-Croatian, Polish, Czech, ...) and the other with (Friend, CD Rack, CD ROM Holder,....).

Comment: Oh I see, maybe I read your question wrong. It is hard to make it perfect but a round about way would be similar to above.

Create a new column for the slicer, you could say:

    IF(table[reference]=10,table[name],"NA")

Do the same for 6.

Your filter will show a result with NA but it would give you the other options you want.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. It's a step in the right direction. But so I can use only one of the filters because if I made a selection in filter one the second filter is showing NA

Comment: Yes, the filters will affect the other since they are both connected to the same data set. Another option that would work would be to 2 new tables with unique names to use in the 2 filters. One table would have the unique list of the names for 10, the other for 6. You could add a relationship only between the names Then, you add the 2 filters and names in the filters would remain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes its bad if there is no chance to disconnect the filters when they aim the same data field. The idea with seperate tables is ok but this would increase the rest of the data model.